# One Half of a Primorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, prime-numbers, terminology, prime-factorization

Is there a name for a half primorial? How should a half primorial be notated?

The first three primorials are 2,6, and 30. The first three half primorials are 1,3, and 15.

I have found that the half primorials are of great importance and need to know if there is any standard terminology or notation for them.

Comment: [OEIS A070826](https://oeis.org/A070826) does not suggest anything

Comment: Perhaps odd primorial would be a good idea...

Comment: Might be nice if you could tell us why you believe them to be of such great importance? Effectively, "half-primorials" are just "odd primorials", as Lucian stated. Odd primorial does seem to have been used before in the literature, for e.g.: http://www.math.klte.hu/publi/load_jpg.php?p=1635

Comment: It is not by mere coincidence that the number 1/2 occurs infinitely many times in the great pattern of the arrangement of prime factors which governs the distribution of the primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How should a half primorial be notated?*

$\dfrac{p\#}2$

> *Is there a name for a half primorial?*

No, there is no established term for this notion.